How do import a component to my Angular app using the design libraries from a framework?
I'm trying to create a layout for a client with pre-existing angular components from their library. I have all my environment for Angular running in my computer and I included the libraries from the DS into my folder app. When I'm trying to create a component for a card (for example), I created the files for the html, ts and css and run my app the design is not charging on my component.
I asked for help from the client and I haven't received any feedback.
I didn't get any errors from my console when I imported the libraries so I'm in a gray area.
Can someone lead me to a video, tutorial or link to resolve my issue?
